# Write to a file on docker container gives error: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to execute the following command:

```
docker exec mydocker echo "hello" >> /usr/local/src/scores.txt
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
No such file or directory
```

But using the following command:

```
docker exec -it mydocker bash
```

I make sure that the file actually exists there. Is there something that I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the echo command in a command string:

```
docker exec mydocker sh -c 'echo "hello" >> /usr/local/src/scores.txt'
```

Verify file contents using:

```
docker exec mydocker cat /usr/local/src/scores.txt
```

Comment: awesome, interesting that you can execute every other command without doing such a thing. Thanks

Comment: There is a good reason for this: it's being interpreted as two commands.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason for this: it's being interpreted as two commands.

**The solution** is as stacksonstacks posted - wrap your container commands in a single shell command:

```
    docker exec mydocker sh -c 'echo "hello" >> /usr/local/src/scores.txt'
```

But why is it happening?

The key is that you've used a bash operator. Similar to any time you run something like:

```
    echo one two >> file.txt
```

The ">>" operator doesn't get passed as an argument to echo (like "one" and "two" do). Instead it executes your echo command and appends its output to a file.

In this case, the ">>" operator is doing the same to your docker exec, and trying to output the results to /usr/local/src/scores.txt and reporting that the directory does not exist (on the host, not the container).

This means that if you ran:

```
    docker exec mydocker echo "hello" >> scores.txt
```

You'd find scores.txt on your host, containing "hello" - the output from the command run on the container.
And as a final test try:

```
    docker exec cf65263ed353 hostname && hostname
```

You'll see it prints the container's hostname (its hash ID), followed by your own. The second command is run on the host.